# Debit Card vs. Bank Account Number (USA)?

Tags: banking, bank-account, money-transfer, debit-card, wire-transfer

I currently have in my possession physical debit card. Don't have my personal bank account number (both USA). I know it can be found online, on physical cheques, welcome material, statements but I just don't have them at this time. Is there any way I could get my bank account number from my actual debit card?

Comment: No. Write the bank a letter and ask them what proof ID you can provide that they will accept. I suspect they will ask you for a Medallion Signature Authentication.

Comment: @keshlam - write the bank a letter and ask a question? That would likely take a long time if you even get a response at all. (Or did you mean email?) Surely calling or walking into a branch would be **much** more efficient.

Comment: I presumed walking into a branch wasn't an option given the question. It's hard to prove identity over the phone; medallion signature guarantee is oriented toward hardcopy (obviously).

Comment: Well, you can use the debit card number (along with pin and ssn) to access information about your account online and get the account number from that - to essentially log into your account at your bank's website when/if you don't have your login details for whatever reason.  Not sure this would be any better (or any different) from accessing your bank account online directly, say from username/password setup.

Answer (score 5):

Just by looking at the card, generally not.

You could look on the back for the customer service phone number, call it, identify yourself to their satisfaction, explain your situation and see if they'll tell you your account number.

Comment: Depends on the bank. Some will give account number over the phone after verification. Others will not. The majority now fall into the "Will not give personal info over the phone"-camp.

Comment: That's why I said "see if", and mentioned that they will want to carefully identify you to their satisfaction before doing that.